# Toggle class of clicked href

Tags: jquery

I have a Ajax request that fires on clicking a href that is part of a set of href's having the same class `.button`. The HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="button-container">
    <a href="#" class="button red" data-id="1"></a>
    <a href="#" class="button red" data-id="2"></a>
    <a href="#" class="button red" data-id="3"></a>
    <a href="#" class="button red" data-id="4"></a>
</div>
```

Since, the href's having the class `.button` are themselves loaded via a separate ajax call into the div `#button-container` and not available during page load, I am using jQuery on() to fire ajax call on clicking the `.button` href's. The javascript looks like this:

```
jQuery('#button-container').on('click', '.button', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var id = jQuery(this).data('id');

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: ajaxVars.ajaxurl,
        type:'POST',
        async: true,
        cache: true,
        timeout: 10000,
        data: 'action=button_action&id=' + id,
        success: function(value){
            if (parseInt(value) == id) {
                jQuery(this).removeClass('red').addClass('green');
            } else {
                jQuery(this).removeClass('green').addClass('red');
            }
        },
        error: function() {
            //alert(error);
        }
    });
});
```

The ajax fires as desired and I get a response from the server upon success. On success I need to toggle the class representing the color of href `.button` from `.red` to `.green` and vice-versa. This is where I have the issue. I get an error `a.ownerDocument is undefined` in the console. This appears to happen when removing the class. Also, I need to "only toggle the class of the clicked href", hence I am using `jQuery(this)`.

Any ideas on how to individually toggle the class of the href's in above scenario?

Regards,
John

Comment: Hmmm, I setup a jsFiddle with this and didn't get the same error. Both true and false in the success method changed the class without error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your `.ajax()` success callback, `this` is not the anchor. You can force it to be the clicked anchor by passing a `context` property as an option:

```
jQuery.ajax({
     url: ajaxVars.ajaxurl,
     type:'POST',
     async: true,
     cache: true,
     timeout: 10000,
     data: 'action=button_action&id=' + id,
     context: this,    // <-- HERE
     success: function(value){
         if (parseInt(value, 10) == id) {
             jQuery(this).removeClass('red').addClass('green');
         } else {
             jQuery(this).removeClass('green').addClass('red');
         }
     },
     error: function() {
         //alert(error);
     }
});
```

Comment: This works! Absolutely simple and the best solution. Thx for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure, but maybe $(this) isn't refering to the button you clicked anymore, try caching $(this) in a variable before the $.ajax call, and then use that variable to remove/add classes.

```
var $this = $(this);
jQuery.ajax({
   ..........
     success: function(value) {
        ......
            $this.removeClass('red').addClass('green');
```

Comment: Your solution works. However, I went with solution being a one liner. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

I would try:

```
if (parseInt(value) == id) {
    jQuery("#" + id).removeClass('red').addClass('green');

} else {
    jQuery("#" + id).removeClass('green').addClass('red');
}
```

and on your html add `id` property to `a` tags